# AngularJS: Service not returning data

Tags: angularjs, json, angular-services

I have been trying to get data from a json file through service in AngularJS(1.5.3). I am unable to retrieve the data from json and display it in the view. I get blank values instead. Below is the code:

```js
//Service

angularStoreApp.factory('dataService', ['$http', function ($http, $q) {

    return {
        getProducts: function () {
            var promise = $http.get('/api/json/products.json')        
        .then(function successCallback(response) {
            if (typeof response.data === 'object') {
                return response.data;
            } else {
                // invalid response
                return "Invalid data";
            }
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            return "Invalid data";
        })
            return promise;
        }
    };
}]);

//Controller

/// <reference path="SearchController.js" />
angularStoreApp.controller('SearchCtrl', ['$scope', 'dataService', function ($scope, dataService) {
      
    $scope.ProductItems = [];
   
    dataService.getProducts()
        .then(function (data) {
            $scope.ProductItems = data;
        });
}]);
```

```html
<blockquote>
    <h4 style="color: salmon">Welcome to the New Store
    <br />
        Please select the products you want and add them to your shopping cart.
    <br />
        When you are done, click the shopping cart icon to review your order and checkout.
    <br />
    </h4>


  
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12" ng-repeat="ProductItem in ProductItems track by $index">
        {{ProductItem.Name}}, {{ProductItem.Price}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Update:

Below is the json data that I have. 
`[{
    "itemName": "Notepad",
    "itemPrice": 12,
    "itemQuantity": 0
},
{
    "itemName": "Pen",
    "itemPrice": 8,
    "itemQuantity": 0
},
{
    "itemName": "Pencil",
    "itemPrice": 5,
    "itemQuantity": 0
}];`

Could anyone help me out.

Comment: Where are you referring your controller in view?

Comment: Drop a few console logs in your controller. Let's see what's happening. Try to console.log the data.

Comment: @Gangadhar: I have used routing.

Comment: @Mathew There are no logs in the console.

Comment: @Sreehari I've tested your code in my system and it is working fine

Comment: Where is your products.json located?

Comment: For me , I see only "," values appearing  in the UI. json file is in my application, as mention in the path in service: '/api/json/products.json'

Comment: what's the entire url? Most likely the json you receive doesn't contain the 'Name' or 'Price' properties. Have you checked case sensitive?

Comment: @fikkatra My json does contain the 'Name' and 'Price' properties. I did check the case sensitive. everything seems ok.

Comment: I did notice that after using `console.log("Invalid data - not an object")` in the else condition, this message is being displayed in the console. I am unable to understand why the if condition is failing in the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after reading the following links

http://www.dwmkerr.com/promises-in-angularjs-the-definitive-guide/

http://bguiz.github.io/js-standards/angularjs/resolving-promises-for-a-controller/

The following is how I modified my code to get it working:

In the config routing section I used the resolve property for that route

```
var angularStoreApp = angular.module('AngularStore', ['ngRoute']);
angularStoreApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/products', {
        templateUrl: '/Views/Store.html',
        controller: 'SearchCtrl',
        resolve: {
            resolvedJSON: function (dataService) {
                return dataService.getProducts();
            }
        }
    })
    .when('/product/:productName', {
        templateUrl: '/Views/product.html',
        controller: 'ProductCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/products'
    });
}]);
```

Now I injected the resolvedJSON in my controller as follows

```
/// <reference path="SearchController.js" />
angularStoreApp.controller('SearchCtrl', ['$scope', 'resolvedJSON',           function ($scope, resolvedJSON) {
$scope.ProductItems = [];
$scope.ProductItems = resolvedJSON;
}]);
```

And my service code as follows:

```
angularStoreApp.factory('dataService', ['$http', function ($http, $q) {
  return {
    getProducts: function () {
        return $http.get('/api/json/products.json')
           .then(function successCallback(response) {
               return response.data;
           }, function errorCallback(response) {
               return "Invalid data";
           })
    }
};
```

following is my json data

```js
[{
   "itemName": "Notepad",
   "itemPrice": 12,
   "itemQuantity": 0
},
{
   "itemName": "Pen",
   "itemPrice": 8,
   "itemQuantity": 0
},
{
    "itemName": "Pencil",
    "itemPrice": 5,
    "itemQuantity": 0
}]
```

My view(Store.html) is something like this:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12" ng-repeat="ProductItem in ProductItems track by $index">
        {{ProductItem.itemName}}, {{ProductItem.itemPrice}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps anyone facing a similar issue as mine. Thank you everyone who steered me to a better and simple answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your first line!

you should pass all the services as string:

```
angularStoreApp.factory('dataService', ['$http', '$q' function ($http, $q) {
```

Comment: $q is not used in the code, so it's just undefined. Not really a problem, although the OP should definitely fix that

Comment: your right  @fikkatra!  I think your answer is correct

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the code snippet working, you need to

- initialize the module in the js: `var angularStoreApp = angular.module('storeapp', []);`
- add `ng-app` in the view
- add `ng-controller` in the view (or use routing)

Forgetting to add `$q` to the dependencies is indeed a mistake, but it doesn't prevent your app from working, as long as you don't use `$q`.

Below is an adjusted, working code snippet. I simulated the http call by returning json wrapped in a promise. If it still doesn't work, the problem is the HTTP call, i.e. the part I commented out. Execute the call in the browser and verify that the correct JSON is returned.

```js
var angularStoreApp = angular.module('storeapp', []);

//Service

angularStoreApp.factory('dataService', ['$http', '$q',
  function($http, $q) {

    return {
      getProducts: function() {
        //simulate promise with json:
        return $q.when([{
          'Name': 'name 1',
          'Price': 1.23
        }, {
          'Name': 'name 2',
          'Price': 4.56
        }]);
        //var promise = $http.get('/api/json/products.json')
        // .then(function successCallback(response) {
        //  if (typeof response.data === 'object') {
        //   return response.data;
        // } else {
        // invalid response
        //   return "Invalid data";
        // }
        // }, function errorCallback(response) {
        //   return "Invalid data";
        // })
        // return promise;
      }
    };
  }
]);

//Controller

/// <reference path="SearchController.js" />
angularStoreApp.controller('SearchCtrl', ['$scope', 'dataService',
  function($scope, dataService) {

    $scope.ProductItems = [];

    dataService.getProducts()
      .then(function(data) {
        $scope.ProductItems = data;
      });
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="storeapp" ng-controller="SearchCtrl">
  <blockquote>
    <h4 style="color: salmon">Welcome to the New Store
    <br />
        Please select the products you want and add them to your shopping cart.
    <br />
        When you are done, click the shopping cart icon to review your order and checkout.
    <br />
    </h4>



    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12" ng-repeat="ProductItem in ProductItems track by $index">
        {{ProductItem.Name}}, {{ProductItem.Price}}
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've replicated your code in [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/kamatuhogu/edit?html,js,output) and it is working fine through I've changed the code for brevity.

The issue might be with below code as it looks for products.json in root folder not in your project folder.

`$http.get('/api/json/products.json')`

Try with removing '/' in the URL.

`$http.get('api/json/products.json')`

Answer (score -1):

1. u forgot the '$q' for minification
2. u should use the var deferred = $q.defer();// (I will add a full code)
3. example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y0g0ft44/11/)

   ```
   angular.module('app', [])
   .controller('ctrl', function(dataService, $scope) {
   var vm = this;
   $scope.ProductItems = [];

   dataService.getProducts()
     .then(function(data) {
       $scope.ProductItems = data;
     });
   })  
   .factory('dataService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {

   function getProducts() {
     var deferred = $q.defer();

     $http.get('https://httpbin.org/get')
       .then(function successCallback(response) {

         if (typeof response.data === 'object') {
           // let say we get list of Products
           deferred.resolve([{
             id: 1,
             name: 'Product1'
           }, {
             id: 2,
             name: 'Product2'
           }, {
             id: 3,
             name: 'Product3'
           }]);
         } else {
           // invalid response
           return "Invalid data";
         }
       }, function errorCallback(response) {
         return deferred.reject("Invalid data");
       })

     return deferred.promise;
   }

   return {
     getProducts: getProducts
   };
    }]);
   ```

Comment: Please try to avoid the explicit promise construction anti pattern! It is really not necessary to construct a deferred object in this case. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: Ok Thanks :) I didn't know it anti pattern

Answer (score -1):

I think one of the problems you have is already mentioned @Ahmad Mobaraki ,and another one is in your `dataService`, the `promise` object returned by `$http.get('/api/json/products.json')` is already consumed by `then()` function, so what you need to do is to create a new `promise` and return it.

Code example:

```
//service
angularStoreApp.factory('dataService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {

    return {
        getProducts: function () {
            var defered = $q.defer();

            $http.get('/api/json/products.json')        
                .then(function successCallback(response) {
                    if (typeof response.data === 'object') {
                        defered.resolve(response.data);

                    } else {
                        // invalid response
                        defered.reject("Invalid data");
                    }
                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                defered.reject("Invalid data");
            });
            return defered.promise;
        }
    };
}]);

//Controller
angularStoreApp.controller('SearchCtrl', ['$scope', 'dataService', function ($scope, dataService) {

    $scope.ProductItems = [];

    dataService.getProducts()
        .then(function (data) {
            $scope.ProductItems = data;
        });
}]);
```

hope this can help you :)

Comment: even if you add 'then' to a promise, it will still return a new promise because promises are chained. Furthermore, try to avoid the explicit promise construction anti patter, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: Thank you, just looking into that :)